# similar AWS CLI query but output is very different, do you know why?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am beginner at AWS CLI and I have a question regarding below 2 queries' output. If someone can help me to understand?

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,
    Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName,
    FromPort:IpPermissions[].FromPort}" --output table

aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].
    [Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId, 
    InstanceType,VpcId,SubnetId,ImageId,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0]]'
```

The output of 2nd cmd gives very nice table view however the first one doesn't can someone check it out?

Answer (score 0):

The APIs you are invoking have varying response formats. Hence the describe-security-groups command is not returning the details in a nice tabular format. The information you are looking for can not be obtained in a tabular format. You can get it in text format though:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].[[GroupName,GroupId,IpPermissions[].FromPort][]]" --output text
```

Comment: Thanks. I liked the output as i needed, but there's little glitch to this above cmd.
It does give only single port output all other ports in the output, so that we say if there are port 80 and 443 open to 0.0.0.0/0 then it will only result port 80.
Can we get listed both of ports?

Comment: @Jatin The information you are looking for can not be obtained in a tabular format. You can get it in text format though. I have updated the answer to reflect that. This is due to the type of data being returned by AWS, which is not compatible with a normal table.